# Someone else with root access to my VPS

Tags: ssh, security, vps

If I have a VPS (on digital ocean) running debian and I share root access to this server via SSH keys or root password with someone, can that person hold my website (the thing that is being hosted on the server) hostage? That is, they have as much access as I do.

Can't I just reset root password and remove all SSH keys to ensure it is safe again?

Otherwise, could I just spin up a new VPS and re-upload all the site code/database and start fresh?

Someone told me the only solution was to throw everything away including the code (magento php code) on the server and start from scratch, but I think this is overkill.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to nuke it, yes. Even removing the current access by removing SSH keys and resetting passwords doesn't guarantee that there isn't a backdoor or some other hidden malware around, assuming this is a malicious attacker. A much better solution is to give a limited "least privilege" account and not give root access to anyone except yourself.

Comment: Really? So I cannot re-use any of my PHP code? Also my databases are screwed as well? I can't believe I need to write every line of code from scratch again.....

Comment: This is why backups are important. There is always a chance for loss of data or destructive action by malicious attackers. While my solution is definitely the most destructive, it is also the most secure. Most VPS providers allow you to take snapshots of your instance. I suggest you set everything up, including security, then take a snapshot. That way if you're  ever compromised you can restore to that snapshot and not lose your work.

Comment: Right I believe snapshots were taking place on a regular basis, would any past snapshot be sufficient? I guess it would have to be a snapshot before the other person got root access, i.e. a point in time that we knew was safe.

Comment: Yes. You'd have to know when the breach occurred and get to one before then.